# padding value using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a value as 233. My requirement is to append '0' to the end of the value , so that total length will be 11 always.

For example 233 -> should be 23300000000 [total length 11]
            56789 -> should be 56789000000  [total length 11]

Is this can be done in xslt ? 
My question is how can we add '0' to the end of the value using a loop ?
i tried with  `<xsl:for-each>` it didnt work. 
If u have any other functions let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That'd be

```
substring(concat("your value", "00000000000"), 1, 11)
```